# Enable android studio smart variable name on implementation

Tags: android-studio

I am following a course on Udacity on android development. When I try something like this with auto complete:

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });
```

you can see that the primitive variable got the names `i`, and `j`. In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFE6iBvUPi4#t=21), I believe android studio automatically gave the int variable the name "position". Do I need to enable this in android studio's settings, or is did the developer in the video just manually changed the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much likely he changed it on his own. That's because the method of the `AdapterView.Class` defines the `OnItemClickListener interface` as follows:

```
public static interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(
                android.widget.AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                android.view.View view,
                int i, // <-- position
                long l);
}
```

As you can see, the position is named `i` that's why the Auto-Completion names it this way.